# How to add column to access database(mdb) table

Tags: .net, database

i have tried using solution explorer ,but there no option to add the column to acces data base table.

The access data base has in .MDB extension format

thanks in advance

Comment: did you even try googling it?

Comment: i have tried but did not get any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access installed? If so just add the column using the design option as with:

http://www.functionx.com/access/topics/column.htm

If you don't have access there are a number of free admin tools for it available online - google some of them e.g..

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/maestro/about/

has a good reputation,